# Unable to make http request to django server using twisted.web.AGENT

Tags: python-2.7, twisted, tcpserver, twisted.web

I have written a basic tcp server factory, server client and a service using twisted. The tcp server acts as the **middleware** between a django server and an another program (let's call it **client** program).

What I want to achieve  -

1.**client** requests the **middleware** tcp server;

2.it sends a string as the request body;

3.the **middleware** tcp server deserializes information from the request.

4.**middleware** furthers the serialized information to the django server.

5.The django server then responds to the **middleware** server which furthers the response to the **client** after serializing the response.

I am able to reach till step 3, but am unable to make any http request to the django server.

The following is my ***middleware.py***

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import ServerFactory
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol

from test_service import MyService


class TCPServerProtocol(Protocol):
    data = ''

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.deferred = self.factory.service.deferred
        self.deferred.addCallback(self.factory.service.s)
        self.deferred.addCallback(self.transport.write)
        self.deferred.addBoth(lambda r: self.transport.loseConnection)

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.data += data

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.forward(self.data)

    def forward(self, data):
        if self.deferred is not None:
            d, self.deferred = self.deferred, None
            d.callback(data)

class TCPServerFactory(ServerFactory):

    protocol = TCPServerProtocol

    def __init__(self, service):
        self.service = service

def runserver(ip, port):
    iface =  {'home': '192.168.0.104', 'work': '127.0.0.1'}
    service = MyService()
    factory = TCPServerFactory(service)
    from twisted.internet import reactor
    reactor.listenTCP(port=port, factory=factory, interface=iface[ip])
    reactor.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    ip = sys.argv[1]
    port = int(sys.argv[2])
    runserver(ip, port)
```

The following is ***test_service.py***

```
from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred

from test_http_client import HTTPClientFactory

class MyService(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.deferred = Deferred()

    def s(self, data):
        kwargs = {}
        kwargs['url'] = b'http://127.0.0.1:8000/some/end/point'
        kwargs['url'] = kwargs['url'].encode('latin-1')
        kwargs['method'] = 'POST'
        kwargs['data'] = data

        client = HTTPClientFactory(**kwargs)
        d = client.deferred
        return d
```

The following is ***test_http_client.py***

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import json

from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol
from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred
from twisted.web.client import Agent, FileBodyProducer
from twisted.web.http_headers import Headers


class HTTPClientProtocol(Protocol):
    def __init__(self, finished):
        self.finished = finished
        self.data = ''

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        print '----------Data Received by HTTPClientProtocol----------'
        print data
        self.data += data

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        print '----------HTTP Client connection Lost----------'
        print reason.getErrorMessage()
        if self.finished is not None:
            print 'finished is not None'
            f, self.finished = self.finished, None
            f.callback(self.data)

class HTTPClientFactory(object):

    """
    Class handling communication with HTTP server.
    """

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        data = kwargs['data'] 
        try:
            body = FileBodyProducer(StringIO(json.dumps(data)))
            print '----------Request body object created----------'
        except Exception as e:
            print '----------Request body object creation FAILURE----------'
            print e
            return e  
        url = kwargs.get('url', None)
        method = kwargs.get('method', None)

        from twisted.internet import reactor
        agent = Agent(reactor)
        if not data:
            body = None

        self.deferred = agent.request(method,
                                    url,
                                    Headers({'Content-Type': ['application/json']}),
                                    bodyProducer=body)

        self.deferred.addCallback(self.get_response)

    def get_response(self, response):
        print 'Response received'
        finished = Deferred()
        response.deliverBody(HTTPClientProtocol(finished))
        return finished
```

**EDITS** Have removed the code which depended on other code irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: Can you try to trim this down into a http://sscce.org ?  There's a lot of code missing here, so I can't try to run your example.  For what it's worth, the presence of Django on the back end doesn't make a difference here: this is just Twisted making an HTTP request.  As you've identified, it works in isolation, so some complex interaction with the rest of your system is causing problems, and without seeing the rest of your system in its entirety I can't say what that is. (Trying to debug your *whole* system isn't really useful to anyone else, so the more you can narrow it down, the better.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the bug.
Below is the corrected code.

```
class TCPServerProtocol(Protocol):

    # data = ''

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.deferred = self.factory.service.deferred
        self.deferred.addCallback(self.factory.service.s)
        self.deferred.addCallback(self.transport.write)
        self.deferred.addBoth(lambda r: self.transport.loseConnection)

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.data = data           # instead of self.data += data
        self.forward(self.data)    # this is the right place to call this method which in turn fires the callback through which the request is made to the server.

    def connectionLost(self, reason): pass
        # this will not be called until the connection from client is ended. 
        # self.forward(self.data)

    def forward(self, data):
        if self.deferred is not None:
            d, self.deferred = self.deferred, None
            d.callback(data)
```

Comment: This code is a syntax error so I'm not sure it's all the way corrected :).  I think you can eliminate `self.data` entirely?